# R Grep Usage: Finding the averages

Tags: r

Object name: Test

```
 Student  HW1  Hw2 HW3  HW4 Hw5
1 Amber   100  100 100  100 100
2 Janet   100  100 100  98   0
3 Zack    100  97  100  100 100
```

How do I find the average of all the homeworks using the grep command. I have to find the average of all columns containing how in its name irrespective of the case.

Answer (score 2):

Your case insensitive `grep` should look similar to this:

```
ix <- grep( "^hw\\d+$", colnames(test), ignore.case= TRUE )
```

You can use this to subset your data frame directly:

```
colMeans( test[ ix ] )

      HW1       Hw2       HW3       HW4       Hw5 
100.00000  99.00000 100.00000  99.33333  66.66667
```

Comment: or you could do `colnames(test)<-toupper(colnames(test))` followed by `ix<-grep("HW",colnames(test)`